# send json request using php for and api

Tags: php, json

I am working on some api in which I send information using json.

POST /api/v3/users/ HTTP/1.1

Host: example.com

Content-Type: application/vnd.api+json

Authorization: Bearer ab1dcb45be7e43db2212b0d2b0ca3892

This is the information. Using this will get that response but I don't know how to use this in php and not use js?

get response:

```
{

    "users": [ {

        "username": "username",

        "phone": "06123",

        "last_name": "myname",

        "address": "some addr",

        "newsletter": true,

        "dob": "1974-12-31",

        "x_id": "123ext",

        "email": "user2@mail.nl",

        "email_verified":  true,

        "social" : {

            "facebook": { "id": "100000730165158"},

            "twitter": {"id": "139029213"},

            "linkedin": {"id": "7EA06I71K5"},

            "google": {"id": "104763295979778440139"}

        }
    }]

}
```

But I don't know how to use this, meaning how to send request.

Comment: There is a good example: http://www.lornajane.net/posts/2011/posting-json-data-with-php-curl

Comment: bro. in this example we himself send $data but in my case that info i will get i have token information. like this url https://ssotest.jibecompany.com/media/docs/api/v3/users.html

Comment: You can add the header to the CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER argument array.

Answer (score 0):

You can store this content in avariable, and then just json_decode it to convert it into php array.

Comment: bro. why i save this value in variable i need this all values from response of json request. how can i get this from......?

Comment: You should call the api vai curl.